# Finite weight spaces for coherent sheaf cohomology

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Given a smooth quasiprojective variety $X$ with a coherent sheaf $E$, if $X$ is not projective, then the sheaf cohomology of $E$ may not be finite-dimensional.  However, if we also have the action of a torus $T$ on $X$ so that $E$ is equivariant, then the cohomology groups are naturally representations of $T$, and it could be the case that the weight spaces are finite-dimensional.  Under what hypotheses will this be true?  For instance, if $X$ has proper fixed locus, is that enough?

Comment: Your hypothesis is not enough.  For instance, start with a coherent sheaf $F$ on a quasi-projective scheme $Y$ such that $H^i(Y,F)$ is not finite-dimensional.  Now take $X$ to be $Y\times \mathbb{G}_m$ with the torus $\mathbb{G}_m$ acting via the natural action on the second factor.  There is a $\mathbb{G}_m$-invariant projection $p:Y\times \mathbb{G}_m\to Y$, and the pullback $E=p^*F$ is a coherent sheaf on $Y\times \mathbb{G}_m$ together with a $\mathbb{G}_m$-linearization.  Using the Leray spectral sequence for $p$ (or other methods), the weight spaces for $H^i(X,E)$ are $H^i(Y,F)$.  

Comment: I think if you add the hypothesis that there is some one-parameter subgroup so that every point of $X$ has a well-defined limit in $X^T$, then the statement should be true. 

Comment: @anon: I still think this is not enough.  Let $\mathbb{G}_m$ act on $\mathbb{P}^2$ by $t\cdot [X_0,X_1,X_2] = [X_0, tX_1, t^2X_2]$.  The fixed points are $p_0 = [1,0,0]$, $p_1=[0,1,0]$ and $p_2=[0,0,1]$.  If you look at the Bialynicki-Birula stratification, then the open stratum limits to $p_0$, a $1$-dimensional stratum limits to $p_1$, and only $p_2$ limits to $p_2$.  So define $X$ to be $\mathbb{P}^2\setminus \{p_2\}$.  This scheme satisfies your hypotheses.  Yet consider the first cohomology of the structure sheaf.  